# How to avoid blocking button actions in a page while progress dialog is shown

Tags: android

In my activity page ,there is a navigation bar on the top with a home button.I don't want to block home button action while progress dialog is shown .How to implement this?

Comment: Post your code, what you have tried?

Comment: I am afraid, you can't do that.